# After Effects math.round Javascript script

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm working on some motion graphics in Adobe After Effects and would like to change one expression control that's based on java but unfortunately I don't know anything about the language..

The expression is:

```
Math.round(thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Percent Control")("Slider"))+"%"
```

It's basically a percentage that goes from 0 to the percentage that you put but I would like to remove the Math.round so it displays decimal points but keep the rest as proper code, sorry for the basic question..

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I thought it would benefit you to know that JavaScript has no relation to Java whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in JavaScript to format a decimal you would do

```
parseFloat(Math.round(someNumber * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
```

where the `toFixed(1)` specifies 1 decimal place, and the `(someNumber * 100) / 100)` simply turns a whole integer into a decimal place float. In your case this should do the trick:

```
parseFloat(thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Percent Control")("Slider")).toFixed(1);
```

I removed the Math.round function since it was giving you problems.

Comment: thank you very much, this gives me 1 decimal place but when the percentage goes from 0-16.5 (my chosen value) the .0 doesnt move at all and it ends up at 17, in the version of @CaptainCarl the decimal value does move and it ends up where I enter (16.5%)

Comment: See my edit. Remove the `Math.round()` part but keep the `parseFloat().toFixed(1)` I mentioned. It should work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim off that part of `Math.round()`. which will leave you with 
`thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Percent Control")("Slider")`

To get a smaller number try:

```
var num = thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Percent Control")("Slider");
var theActualNumberToUse = num.toFixed(1);
```

Edit: Here's a fiddle that seems to work properly :) http://jsfiddle.net/3t9HN/

Comment: Hehe thank you very much, only problem is I now have 13 decimal places, could you tell me how to put just one?

Comment: If it's an animation, does it matter that it's a long value? I'm no After Effects or animation expert so I don't know if you visually see a difference or it's just for your own comfort(I tend to round things to calm my nerves, I'm weird)

Comment: yep, unfortunately I have a big string of numbers on screen, its an infographic for a promo video

Comment: I've edditted my answer. Could you try that?